# Saving an image from HTTP Post (Not using FileUpload Control)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page (May even use a handler), anyway.. that is awaiting an HTTP POST with a number of variables including an image encoded as a multipart/form-data Content Type.

How do I save the image from the HTTP Post?

This image encoded int the HTTP POST is from another site and is not from a local FileUpload Control.

**EDIT :**

Hang on, am I being daft.. can't I just use Request.Files..

May be as simple as http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Upload_multiple_files_using_the_HtmlInputFile_control.aspx

-- Lee

Comment: Indeed, Request.Files is win.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the posted form is multipart/form-data you can just check the Request.Files collection to check if there should be any files posted with your form :)